# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Estou estudando Asp.Net Core MVC e estou criando uma aplicação onde tenho Fornecedores e Produtos.
Ao criar um novo produto, é necessário informar um fornecedor porém, estou tendo o erro "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

O que devo fazer para corrigir?

Essa é a Controller e o método GET Create:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var produtoViewModel = await PopularFornecedores(new ProdutoViewModel());

        return View(produtoViewModel);
    }
```

Essa é minha View Create:
[image: View de criação do produto]

Essa é minha ViewModel:

```
public class ProdutoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0] é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Fornecedor")]
    public Guid FornecedorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} precisa ter enre {2} e {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} precisa ter enre {2} e {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImagemUpload { get; set; }

    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo?")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public FornecedorViewModel Fornecedor { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FornecedorViewModel> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

E esse é o erro que está dando na hora de exibir o formulário para cadastrar um produto:
[image: Stacktrace do erro]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um pequeno erro de digitação no atributo da propriedade `FornecedorId`

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0] é obrigatório")]
```

Altere para

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
```

Comment: Nossa kkkkk, era só isso mesmo!

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Acontece kkk, Eu testei seu código e fiquei um tempinho para ver que era esse o problema.